# How to show only the year field in Sharepoint date and time(Today)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

I want a field in which only the year of the present date(Today) is shown.I had tried many methods but couldn't find any solutions.Can anyone help me with the problem.

I am new to sharepoint, so please explain me step by step.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try to use Calculated Field with following formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(YEAR([Created]))
```

It will display year from item creation date. More info about calculated fields can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx)